# Python circular class use

Tags: python, class

I have a couple of classes:

1. A base class (for exemple a class person) defined in a certain file
2. Different classes inheriting from the base class (for exemple a class employee and a class boss) defined in a certain file
3. A big class having 2. class instance as attribute (for exemple a class company) defined in a certain file

person.py file

```
class Person:
   # define some stuffs
```

employee.py file

```
from person import Person

class Employee(Person):
   def __init__(self, company):
       self.company = company


class Boss(Person):
   def __init__(self, company):
       self.company = company
   def interact_with_employee(self):
       do some stuff using self.company.employee
```

company.py file

```
import employee import Employee, Boss

class Company:
   self.employee = Employee(company = self)
   self.boss = Boss(company = self)
```

In my script I would basically call:

```
import Company
company = Company()
company.boss.interact_with_employee()
```

What I want is:

employee.py file

```
from person import Person
from company import Company

class Employee(Person):
   def __init__(self, company:Company):
       self.company = company


class Boss(Person):
   def __init__(self, company:Company):
       self.company = company
   def interact_with_employee(self):
       do some stuff using self.company.employee
```

Obviously there is a circular import even if I define company in the Person base class.
I would like to mention that employee and boss's company attribute is of type Company without being confronted to circular import. Should I drop this idea or is there a way to do this cleanly (including changing the structure of the files etc)?

Comment: I don't see a circular import. You do, however, seem to be confusing classes and modules. I picture something like `person.py` defining `Persion`, `employee.py` using `from person import Person` and defining `Employee` and `Boss`, and `company.py` defining `Company` and using `from employee import Employee, Boss`. Your script would use `from company import Company`, and possibly some form of `import person` and `import employees` when and if needed.

Comment: It may seems like I confuse them because I over simplified my code. I will edit it. @chepner

Comment: There are no circular imports here. It's true that your script *tries* to import `person` twice (once explicitly, again when `company` imports `employee` which imports `person`), but the import system already handles this via caching. A module can be imported multiple times, but it will only be *defined* once.

Comment: A circular import would occur if `person` tried to import `company`, for example.

Comment: There is, company try to import employee and employee try to import company

Comment: You don't need to import modules just for type hints: `def __init__(self, company: 'Company')`. (If you use `from __future__ import annotations`, you don't even need the quotes.) (When you *do* need a circular import, that means you are splitting a single file into two files that shouldn't be split up.)

Comment: Hinting this way doesn't allow Pylance to recognize the type right?

Comment: But splitting seems appropriate here as combining the three files into one would result in 15 classes and 1500 lines in the same file

Comment: You say that like it's a problem. It *might* suggest you have too many classes, but what benefit does spreading them across multiple files have over having them in a single file?

Comment: Plus here Company is already implemented that's not really how __future__ should be used? (I'm not familiar with its use)

Comment: I prefer having the type not hinted over having a 1500 lines file but I guess that's personal tastes

Comment: `__future__` refers to the "future" of the language itself. `annotations`, for example, says that function and variable annotations won't be evaluated at runtime, as they currently are. It allows you to *opt in* to a backwards-incompatible language feature *now*, rather than waiting until it becomes mandatory in a future Python version to fix your code to conform.

Comment: You can do both: you don't need to import a module *just* to get a name for type hinting. You never have; strings as forward references have always been allowed, and `annotations` lets you get ready now for a future where the strings won't be necessary.

Comment: My aim is for the langage support tool used to recognize the company attribute as a Company instance. But I don't see how future can do this